# Can WebDAV be configured to give me access to directories outside of its own root?

Tags: configuration, webdav

I need to read and write to a directory which is a peer to my WebDAV root.  The WebDAV root is "$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/webdav".  I would like to write to "$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/myApp".  Can it be configured to allow this?  Perhaps via a symbolic link?

---

Crickets... chirp... chirp... chirp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symlink will work fine, assuming your WebDAV server is configured to follow them.  For Apache, you want "Options FollowSymLinks" in the DAV config, probably.  See the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options) for details on that.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat, so I edited the root tag of context.xml in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf from <Context> to <Context allowLinking="true">.  Works perfectly.